# How HFTP is different from HTTP to read the data from remote hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop

How  HFTP is different from HTTP to read the data from remote hadoop cluster ?

HFTP vs HTTP (Difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HFTP is used to read data from remote clusters of different hadoop versions. It is independent of hadoop version in the destination cluster.

HFTP is used in conjuction with disctp.

HFTP is read only unlike http.

Have a look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-hadoop/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/fs.html